# Cycling as an array returned by the method fetch_assoc () PHP & Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I ask those who have a bit of kindness to help me in this thing, I would like to cycle this dynamic array returned from a store procedure mysql, since it is dynamic and will never know the index I have no idea how to do, I know only the array with two key is the title that will give the list and arrays with   [NomeProdotto] etc .. will list items.

This is Array to loop:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NomeMenu] => Pizze
            [IDMenu] => 1
        )
```

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [IDMenu] => 1
        [IDProdotto] => 2
        [NomeProdotto] => Eurobar
        [PrezzoProdotto] => 5.00
        [IngredientiProdotto] => Pomodoro, Mozzarella, Patate bollite, Prosciutto
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [IDMenu] => 1
        [IDProdotto] => 4
        [NomeProdotto] => Parripusu
        [PrezzoProdotto] => 6.00
        [IngredientiProdotto] => Pomodoro, Mozzarella, Salsiccia, Funghi, Origano
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [IDMenu] => 1
        [IDProdotto] => 5
        [NomeProdotto] => U Chianu a Muccusa
        [PrezzoProdotto] => 4.00
        [IngredientiProdotto] => Pomodoro, Mozzarella, Origano
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [IDMenu] => 1
        [IDProdotto] => 6
        [NomeProdotto] => Vaddruni
        [PrezzoProdotto] => 5.00
        [IngredientiProdotto] => Pomodoro, Mozzarella, Piselli, Uovo, Prosciutto cotto, Funghi, Origano
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [NomeMenu] => Supplementi
        [IDMenu] => 3
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [IDMenu] => 3
        [IDProdotto] => 8
        [NomeProdotto] => Prosciutto
        [PrezzoProdotto] => 1.00
        [IngredientiProdotto] => 
    )
```

)

I solved this way

```
    $i = 0;
    $menus = array();
    if ($mysqli->multi_query("CALL getMenuLocale(" . $_REQUEST['locale'] .   ")")) {
        while ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            $mysqli->next_result();
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

                    $menus[$i] = $row;

                }
                $result->free();
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }
```

but I get an error as soon as published on Godaddy :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() on line 758**

I read that the solution might be to use fetch_assoc () instead of fetch_all (), and it returns the array mentioned above, how can I cycle through php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use fetch_all. As the name implies, it returns the complete dataset. So use fetch_assoc, this will return a row of the result in the form of an array.
Like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //
}
```

This leaves you with $row being the array with the irregular number of elements. You can also iterate through this array. So the code would look like:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        //$key is 'IDMenu' for example
        //$value is '1' for example

        //you can then use these variables
    }
}
```

This way it doesn't matter if you have 2 of 5 elements in the array, you can still use what values you have.

I also see you are trying to add the $row array to another $menus array? What is the purpose of this? Because you are essentially recreating the query result this way...

All things aside, perhaps it is a good idea to look at some [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) if you have a hard time with working with arrays ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer,  I am a beginner and I'm studying, I do not understand why I have given a negative vote on a question as these stumenti need to learn and I think I'm not the only one who has had these doubts, however, I try your olution and let you know thanks again